# Undefined variable: total

Tags: php

I'm having problems with this

```
$total += $rows['price'] * $qty;
```

Notice: Undefined variable: total in D:\xampp\htdocs\WBPL-MusicLightDev\inc\functions.inc.php on line 42

```
function wbpl_showCart() {
    global $db;
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',', $cart);
        //$contents = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
        }
        echo '<form action="index.php?page=cart&action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
        echo '<table border=0 align="center" class="table table-bordered">';


        foreach ($contents as $id => $qty) {
            $sql = "SELECT * from wbpl_product WHERE kd_product = '$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            //extract($row);

            echo    '<tr>
                        <td>Brand</td>
                        <td colspan="4">'. $rows['kd_product'] .'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brand</td>
                        <td colspan="4">'. $rows['nama_brand'] .'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Instrument Type</td>
                            <td colspan="4">'. $rows['nama_instype'] .'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr">
                    <td rowspan="2">Price</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Rp. ' . $rows['price'] . '</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="qty' . $id . '" value="' . $qty . '" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>

                    <td rowspan="2">Rp. ' . ($rows['price'] * $qty) . '</td>

                    <td><a href="index.php?page=cart&action=delete&id=' . $id . '" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><br></td></tr>';
            $total += $rows['price'] * $qty;
        }
        echo '</table>';
        $qty = getQty();


        echo '<p>Sub Total: <strong> Rp. ' . $total . '</strong></p>';



        //session_register('totalbayar');
        $_SESSION['totalbayar'] = $total;
        echo '<div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update cart</button></div>';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Keranjang belanja masih kosong.</p>';
    }
    //return join('', $output);
}
```

Comment: do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add something to a non-existent value; 
The first call would be: null += $rows['price'] * $qty;
This is not possible, so add

> $total = 0;

before your foreach loop!

```
    function wbpl_showCart() {
    global $db;
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if ($cart) {
        $items = explode(',', $cart);
        //$contents = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
        }
        echo '<form action="index.php?page=cart&action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
        echo '<table border=0 align="center" class="table table-bordered">';

        $total = 0;
        foreach ($contents as $id => $qty) {
            $sql = "SELECT * from wbpl_product WHERE kd_product = '$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
            //extract($row);

            echo    '<tr>
                        <td>Brand</td>
                        <td colspan="4">'. $rows['kd_product'] .'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brand</td>
                        <td colspan="4">'. $rows['nama_brand'] .'</td>
                    <tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td>Instrument Type</td>
                            <td colspan="4">'. $rows['nama_instype'] .'</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr">
                    <td rowspan="2">Price</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Rp. ' . $rows['price'] . '</td>
                    <td rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="qty' . $id . '" value="' . $qty . '" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>

                    <td rowspan="2">Rp. ' . ($rows['price'] * $qty) . '</td>

                    <td><a href="index.php?page=cart&action=delete&id=' . $id . '" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><br></td></tr>';
            $total += $rows['price'] * $qty;
        }
        echo '</table>';
        $qty = getQty();


        echo '<p>Sub Total: <strong> Rp. ' . $total . '</strong></p>';



        //session_register('totalbayar');
        $_SESSION['totalbayar'] = $total;
        echo '<div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update cart</button></div>';
        echo '</form>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Keranjang belanja masih kosong.</p>';
    }
    //return join('', $output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `$total` variable:

```
$total = 0;
```

before going into the foreach-loop

Problem is:

`$total += ...;` means add `...` to the value of `$total`, but `$total` isn't yet defined at the first iteration through the loop what causes the notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
```

and set this before using $total will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

`$x += y` implies first reading the variables value then adding something and then (re-)assign the result. During the first iteration of your foreach loop there is no variable `$total` to read from when the `+=` operator is executed, hence the warning.
Initialize the variable before the loop.

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($contents as $id => $qty) {
  [...]
  $total += something;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `+=` operator you have to have already defined the left side variable. You can solve this problem by initializing `$total` before its `$total += ...` use:

```
$total = 0;
foreach (...)
    $total += ...
```

This is because `$total += $x` is internally converted into `$total = $total + $x`, therefore the first time you use it, `$total` in undefined.